# the [[0]*n]*m generated List[List[]] question python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why we change the value of `a[0][0]` and `a[:][0]` are all changed with the following `list[list[]]` initialization method?

```
a= [[0]*n]*m

a
```

Out[2]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

```
a[0][0]=5

a
```

Out[4]: [[5, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0]]